# To sum the two non numeric columns

Tags: sql, oracle, aggregate-functions

Am using oracle 12c. I have 4 columns:

```
country   student_id (primary)  start_level     end_level
-------   --------------------  -----------     ---------
India     I20                   L3              L12
India     I21                   L5              L9
China     c10                   L4              L11
USA       U20                   L2              L9
Canada    C20                   L9              L12
```

From the above table structure I want to group by country wise total students with sum of levels.  For example the output like below:

```
Country|  Total_students| Total_levels
India                  2            15
```

(Total level calculation : L3 to L12=10 + L5 to L9 =5. So, total levels 15)

Can I use substr to find the level values or whatever is best?

Comment: If you need to do arithmetic operation on the levels, you should store the data in numeric format instead.

Comment: Why are start_level and end_level strings ('L3' to 'L12') and not numbers (3 to 12)? Then: if they were numbers, would you know how to solve the problem? And if so, do you know how to convert a string like 'L12' to the number 12? Finally, what is the format of the "level" columns - the letter L followed by the relevant number?

Comment: So if start_level is L3 and end_level is L3 then the total level is 1?

Answer (score 2):

You shouldn't be storing your `start_level` and `end_level` in a string format, it should be an integer and you should drop the `L` in front of it (i.e. `L3` becomes just the integer `3`.) I am assuming you cannot redesign your database at this point though, so try the following:

```
WITH temp_table AS (
    SELECT country, 
           student_id,
           CAST(SUBSTR(start_level,2,10) AS INT) AS start_int,
           CAST(SUBSTR(end_level,2,10) AS INT) AS end_int
    FROM my_table)
SELECT COUNTRY, 
       COUNT(student_id) AS TOTAL_STUDENTS, 
       SUM(end_int - start_int + 1) AS Total_Levels
FROM temp_table
GROUP BY COUNTRY
ORDER BY COUNTRY
```

This uses a Common Table Expression (The WITH clause) to turn your table into one with integer format numbers. The `SUBSTR()` command will start at the second digit and go out to the next 10. In this case, it doesn't have that many so it will stop when it runs out of characters. If you have level `L12000000000` for example, then you will have to increase that argument (I don't expect this to be the case). After that, it casts that string into an integer format using `CAST()`.

Now you are ready to select from your CTE. The query is fairly straight forward from there, as shown.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `regexp_substr()` to extract the digits:

```
select country,
       sum(cast(regexp_substr(end_level, '[0-9]+') as number) -
           cast(regexp_substr(start_level, '[0-9]+') as number) +
           1)

from t
group by country;
```

Answer (score 1):

Something like

```
select   country, count(student_id) as total_students,
         sum(to_number(substr(end_level, 2)) - to_number(substr(start_level, 2)) + 1 )
                                    as total_levels
from     your_table
group by country
;
```